# When the cache is not defined, does HystrixCommand definitely execute `run` or `fallback`

Tags: java, hystrix

I need to wait synchronously for some logic of the HystrixCommand to finish, so I added a CountDownLatch and released it in run and fallback.

```
public class AsyncHystrixCommand extends HystrixCommand implements SofaHystrixInvokable {

    @Override
    protected Object run() throws Exception {
        // part1 sync
        this.syncCall();
        lock.countDown();
        // part2 async
        return this.asyncCall();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getFallback() {
        if (lock.getCount() > 0) {
            lock.countDown();
        }
    }
}
```

Then the main thread will be blocking via `lock.wait`, but if `run` or `fallback` is not executed, this will wait forever.

In the [flowchart of Hystrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQYr8.png), if cache is not defined, can Hystrix guarantee that `run` or `fallback` will be executed? Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

HystrixCommand works asynchronously using RxJava 1.x, but it supports synchronous execution.

All you need to do is just calling `execute()` method with your command like below.

```
Object result = new YourHystrixCommand().execute()`
```

Or you can wait with `Future` or `Observable` by yourself in case of using `queue()` or `observe()`.